# DOMXPath $html->query('//p[@class="myclass"]/a')->item(0); not working

Tags: php, null, domxpath

DOMXPath `$html->query('//p[@class="myclass"]/a')->item(0);` is not working.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p class="username">
<img src="http://static1.tryal.com/img/b.gif" onclick="lalalaa()" class="a12s_iYblt4hN_DkIt_GoiyOtu8 opsi" />
<b>
<a href="/about"><b>Lalala.</b></a>
</b>
</p>


$name = $html->query('//p[@class="username"]/a')->item(0)->nodeValue; 
//This doesn't return the name "Lalala.";

$name = $html->query('//p[@class="username"]')->item(0)->nodeValue; 
//This works just fine.
```

Why isn't this tree working? Am I typing it wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is it perhaps because the anchor `<a>` is not the immediate child of paragraph `<p>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xpath you have specified didn't provide any result (or an result with no elements to be precise). You can fix that by not letting the `b` element slip through:

```
$name = $html->query('//p[@class="username"]/b/a')->item(0)->nodeValue; 
                                            ^^^
```

or by not making `a` a direct/immediate child from `p` but somewhere deeper as well (*descendant of*, double slash `//` in xpath):

```
$name = $html->query('//p[@class="username"]//a')->item(0)->nodeValue; 
                                            ^^
```

Comment: Yea thats it, thank you very much, and also, since I'm used to use JQUery isn't there a way to fetch the "a" ignoring the B? since its a grandchild of P?

Comment: See the second variant, it should do so.

Comment: hmm thank you very much, but another thing, do you guys know if its faster to fetch directly or put each descendant?
also since we are here, how do I do to use a starts with selector, I saw something once like this: starts-with but I couldn't find it anymore.

Comment: I actually don't, where do I click, I want to accept your answer.

Comment: Great :) Helped me out trying to figure out this DOM stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$name = $html->query('//p[@class="username"]//a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

You are looking for 'a' child of (single slash) 'p', while what you want I understand is 'a' **descendant of** (double slash) 'p'